# Decode URL in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

Can anyone explain me how to decode a URL in Blackberry.....????

Comment: the url is [link](http%3A%2F%2Fclickserve.cc-dt.com%2Flink%2Ftplclick%3Flid%3D41000000024810251%26pubid%3D21000000000280437%26redirect%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.abebooks.com%2Fservlet%2FBookDetailsPL%3Fbi%3D4299744197%26cm_ven%3Dsws%26cm_cat%3Dsws%26cm_pla%3Dsws%26cm_ite%3D4299744197")

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Accounts-API/msg/6c1b5e7e5a2226be

Comment: @Vivart: I think the the decoding is still not working by using the above as the browser continues to give the Dialog message . **The Protocol specified is not supported by the handheld.Please try a different URL**. Do you have any idea on this........?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decode url using decode function

```
  public static String decode(String s, String enc)
    throws UnsupportedEncodingException{

    boolean needToChange = false;
    int numChars = s.length();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(numChars > 500 ? numChars / 2 : numChars);
    int i = 0;

    if (enc.length() == 0) {
        throw new UnsupportedEncodingException ("URLDecoder: empty string enc parameter");
    }

    char c;
    byte[] bytes = null;
    while (i < numChars) {
        c = s.charAt(i);
        switch (c) {
        case '+':
            sb.append(' ');
            i++;
            needToChange = true;
            break;
        case '%':
            /*
             * Starting with this instance of %, process all
             * consecutive substrings of the form %xy. Each
             * substring %xy will yield a byte. Convert all
             * consecutive  bytes obtained this way to whatever
             * character(s) they represent in the provided
             * encoding.
             */

            try {

                // (numChars-i)/3 is an upper bound for the number
                // of remaining bytes
                if (bytes == null)
                    bytes = new byte[(numChars-i)/3];
                int pos = 0;

                while ( ((i+2) < numChars) &&
                        (c=='%')) {
                    int v = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(i+1,i+3),16);
                    if (v < 0)
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern - negative value");
                    bytes[pos++] = (byte) v;
                    i+= 3;
                    if (i < numChars)
                        c = s.charAt(i);
                }

                // A trailing, incomplete byte encoding such as
                // "%x" will cause an exception to be thrown

                if ((i < numChars) && (c=='%'))
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                     "URLDecoder: Incomplete trailing escape (%) pattern");

                sb.append(new String(bytes, 0, pos, enc));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern - "
                + e.getMessage());
            }
            needToChange = true;
            break;
        default:
            sb.append(c);
            i++;
            break;
        }
    }

    return (needToChange? sb.toString() : s);
}
```

Comment: I have tried the above code, but the browser gives a Dialog message  ** The Protocol specified is not supported by the handheld.Please try a different URL** . Even without using the decode method it gives the same message. Any Idea...?

Comment: your url wrong, (i think you copy eclipse jre console), my function decode your url correctly, when i remove dash  "437%2-­6redirect%3".

Comment: sorry I could nt get you excaltly. But the url is correct as the URL has already been used in  android projects (using URL encoder)

Comment: your sample url has "-" between decoded digits, remove and decode url. will remove and decode url, and launch default browser on device, url redirect abebooks site.

Answer (score 2):

I found this answer in Blackberry support forum: [URL Encoding and Decoding](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/URL-Encoding-and-Decoding/m-p/137165#M15627)

I tried it and it worked.